# How can a question be protected by Community? Why is the date format different there?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-interface, protected-posts

I don't understand the following screenshot I took a moment ago:

> [image]

1. How can Community, and not a named moderator, protect something?
2. Why is the date and time format in the *protected* message different from all other date and time formats on this site?

Comment: If someone has a better topic title, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If 3 or more answers of user having < 10 rep is deleted, the question gets auto-protected. This is because majority of the time, the "answers" are me-too posts rather than just answers and [was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91728/133693) as part of a feature request.
2. Is a bug, being tracked at Meta.SO: [“Migrated from” banner looks wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107374/migrated-from-banner-looks-wrong)

Comment: [This is exactly what happened](http://superuser.com/questions/115369/where-are-firefox-personas-images-saved) in the topic I read. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, @DanielBeck