# In what circumstance will question be 'protected'?

Tags: discussion, community-user

It's a well known fact that those users with 15,000+ reputation have the ability to protect questions from users with less than 10 reputation on the site.

I recently came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page) where the `Community` user protected the question (I couldn't find the question, so I found one from Stack Overflow).
`Community` can own edits from anonymous users, but can it also 'protect' questions without any user intervention?

If so, how?
If not, how was that question protected by `Community`?

Comment: a portion of your q is answered here.  http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3500/how-can-a-question-be-protected-by-community-why-is-the-date-format-different-t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When enough answers by new users are deleted from a question by moderators, the question will automatically be protected by the Community user.

Comment: Who are the answers deleted by. Are they automatically deleted by the `Community` user if it has enough downvotes, or is it up to the moderators to decide?

Comment: @zyboxenterprises: Moderators usually

Comment: It will usually be moderators, but normal users can "recommend deletion" from the low quality queue and higher reputation users can actually delete posts if 3 of them cast a delete vote on a post. http://superuser.com/help/privileges